# Angular sending POST base64 data vs BLOB image

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to upload a file to my server. The problem is right now i'm using a plugin cropping image and the result from cropped image is `base64` data.

My question is: should i convert it to `blob` or just send `base64` data to my server?. I've already make my PHP can read both request.

I've tried both but seem don't have any different in term of speed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you will be spending additional time for converting to blob and sending it.

If you convert to blob and send it will be in JSON and that will cause control chars to be encoded. That brings additional work. If performance is not an issue go ahead and use base64 in my opinion.

Comment: Hi pox. if you don't mind i want to ask one more question. do you have idea to reduce image file size using javascript? when i crop the image become bigger 4times. thanks

Comment: That would be another question for SO